# How to install designate and trove on OpenStack Kilo (Ubuntu 14.04) deployed with Mirantis Fuel 7.0

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

We've set a basic environment using Mirantis Fuel with 3 controller/storage nodes and 3 computes. We've used Fuel to install the base system and then we added some extra components like FWaaS plugin for neutron.

The problem we're facing now is we can add some other components like designate (DNSaaS) nor trove (DBaaS). Wheater I follow the official guides from git-hub (trying to compile from python sources) or add some extra repos (ubuntu-cloud-archive) I always run into dependency problems.

I think the problem is, some of the packages installed trough fuel are not ubuntu natives but re-compiled and modified by mirantis. For example, if I list some neutron packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep neutron
ii  neutron-common                      1:2015.1.1-1~u14.04+mos5355            all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - common
ii  neutron-dhcp-agent                  1:2015.1.1-1~u14.04+mos5355            all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - DHCP agent
rc  neutron-l3-agent                    1:2015.1.1-1~u14.04+mos5348            all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - l3 agent
ii  neutron-lbaas-agent                 1:2015.1.1-1~u14.04+mos739             all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - LBaaS agent
ii  neutron-metadata-agent              1:2015.1.1-1~u14.04+mos5355            all          Neutron is a virtual network service for Openstack - metadata agent
ii  neutron-plugin-ml2                  1:2015.1.1-1~u14.04+mos5355            a
```

They have a base version and an added mos (Mirantis OpenStack) version.

If I try to install trove this happens:

```
apt-get install trove-api
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 trove-api : Depends: trove-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This happens in a lot of packages. So my question would be, is ther a way to add extra packages for this specific distribution of MOS? Maybe some Mirantis extra repo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirantis Fuel deploys hardened openstack packages to nodes and uses the fuel head node as a local repo mirror (if configured) and it also configures the apt sources on all nodes to be subscribed to mirantis openstack repositories.
Look at the openstack nodes repository sources, it will look something like this

> deb http://172.25.10.2:8080/liberty-8.0/ubuntu/auxiliary auxiliary
>   main restricted deb http://mirror.fuel-infra.org/mos-repos/ubuntu/8.0/
>   mos8.0-holdback main restricted deb
>   http://mirror.fuel-infra.org/mos-repos/ubuntu/8.0/ mos8.0-security
>   main restricted deb http://mirror.fuel-infra.org/mos-repos/ubuntu/8.0/
>   mos8.0-updates main restricted deb
>   http://172.25.10.2:8080/liberty-8.0/ubuntu/x86_64 mos8.0 main
>   restricted deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main
>   universe multiverse deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   trusty-updates main universe multiverse deb
>   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe multiverse

In the example above the fuel mirror is not local - and the Ubuntu repos are main, updates and security. I.E not subscribed to the Ubuntu Cloud Archive

to enable the Ubuntu Cloud Archive on OpenStack nodes prior to deployment of OpenStack you can use the fuel settings menu to add additional (non-default) repos.

[image: fuel add repo]

to add Ubuntu cloud repositories after you have deployed Openstack you will need to configure controllers manually such as:

> How to Enable and Use Mitaka
>
> NOTE: Mitaka cloud archive only supported on Trusty
>
> sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:mitaka Liberty
>
> NOTE: Liberty cloud archive only supported on Trusty
>
> sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:liberty Kilo
>
> NOTE: Kilo cloud archive only supported on Trusty
>
> sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:kilo Juno
>
> NOTE: Juno cloud archive only supported on Trusty
>
> sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:juno Icehouse
>
> NOTE: Precise only - Icehouse is the base Openstack release in Trusty

Of note, there are some community plugins on github for Mirantis Fuel
here https://github.com/openstack/?query=fuel-plugin

this are not/not yet official fuel plugins but do contain trove
https://github.com/openstack/fuel-plugin-dbaas-trove
and designate
https://github.com/openstack/fuel-plugin-designate

Also - Fuel deploys and maintains OpenStack using puppet and updating the Openstack version or patching later MOS releases might break any manually configured packages - or- vice versa, manually deploying and maintaing packages and configurations may break any management features built into fuel.

Comment: Is it posible, once deployed, to add new repos without breaking the installed packages? I know about the fuel local/onlin repos, and I visited the cloud archive and downloaded some packages manually, but trying to install them with dpkg -i file.deb always brings incompatibilities.

Comment: yes it should be possible so long as you subscribe to the Ubuntu cloud archive for Kilo on Trusty, install designate and trove with apt-get and let the package manager resolve dependencies (maybe just ensure that they both have the same overall python version dependency- 2.7?). Trove and Designate, like all openstack projects are stand alone i.e. the installer is not going to make a dependency of keystone or neutron, I think you are thinking that Trove etc won't recognize that keystone etc. is installed because they have different names to the main openstack packages, they're not dependencies